# Is it possible to successfully send a spoofed UDP header with a completely unrelated source IP?

Tags: network, ip-spoofing, udp

I've read that many networks use ingress/egress filtering to eliminate the number of spoofed UDP packets sent and received by their network.

Given that network provides have been much more diligent in restricting the amount of spoofed UDP packets sent and received by their networks, is it possible to send a UDP packet with a spoofed header that is drastically different than it's actual IP address?

Besides blocking spoofed packets from leaving their networks, in which other ways can network providers ensure that they are not passing along or sending spoofed UDP packets?

Comment: I think any answer depends on the ISP and the methods of filtering. Is it possible? Yes, if you find a way around their filters.

Answer (score 3):

1. It is possible to spoof IP addresses. The issue is always the underlying protocol. For TCP/IP, you're almost out of luck unless you don't proceed with a full handshake. For UDP however, if you don't care about a response and aren't trying to build fault tolerance, you can use it.
2. There are several ways routers can stop IP address spoofing. The main ways for Cisco routers are:

**LAN**

Involve any solution that attempts to [minimize asymmetric
routing](http://www.cisco.com/web/services/news/ts_newsletter/tech/chalktalk/archives/200903.html), e.g. Spanning tree protocol [STP](http://docwiki.cisco.com/wiki/Internetwork_Design_Guide_--_UDP_Broadcast_Flooding#Implementing_UDP_Flooding). Naturally a
spoofed UDP packet won't have a symmetric route. The only problem is
that the directed graph issue would entail a subset of nodes in the
routing to support STP. Also, UDP may not be affected.

**WAN**

[RFC 1812](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1812) addresses your concern. Note the fact that there are a lot of asymmetric routes on the internet, so it becomes a harder task.
The above RFC was referenced [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2827#page-5):

*"We considered suggesting routers also validate the source IP address
of the sender as suggested in [8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1812), but that methodology will not
operate well in the real networks out there today. The method
suggested is to look up source addresses to see that the return path
to that address would flow out the same interface as the packet
arrived upon. With the number of asymmetric routes in the Internet,
this would clearly be problematic."*